# python twitter library rate limit check

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, twitter

I am trying to find out my rate limit remaining by using rate_limit_remaining call, but it doesn't seems work properly. According to pydoc:

```
class TwitterResponse(__builtin__.object)
 |  Response from a twitter request. Behaves like a list or a string
 |  (depending on requested format) but it has a few other interesting
 |  attributes.
 |  
 |  `headers` gives you access to the response headers as an
 |  httplib.HTTPHeaders instance. You can do
 |  `response.headers.get('h')` to retrieve a header.
 |  
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  rate_limit_limit
 |      The rate limit ceiling for that given request.
 |  
 |  rate_limit_remaining
 |      Remaining requests in the current rate-limit.
 |  
 |  rate_limit_reset
 |      Time in UTC epoch seconds when the rate limit will reset.
```

---

My code:

---

```
from twitter import *
t = Twitter(
    auth=OAuth('all the tokens'))

t.TwitterResponse.rate_limit_remaining
```